# Switching from Top View to Perspective

Tags: camera

I'm having this problem when switching from any orthographic view to perspective view. If I'm into one of the orthographic views and zoom in to see the object a little better if I'm switching right away to perspective mode the screen goes in another completely different direction. I have to zoom out in order to bring my object back. How do I get a seamless transition from one mode to another? Trying to have the camera focused and not moving. Thank you.

Comment: Use layouts. Instead of changing the view, change to a different layout that uses the perspective view on one and the orthographic in another.

Comment: Can't be sure, but have a play with Edit > Preferences > Navigation, to see if there are some settings you feel better with? Are you describing Auto Perspective?